# extracting road names from openstreetmap

Tags: geolocation, openstreetmap

Is it possible to get a list of streets/roads from openstreetmaps with latitude, longitude and postcode for one of London's suburbs?

I am using this link to get some information

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=52.5487429714954&lon=-1.81602098644987&zoom=18&addressdetails=1

but unfortunately I have to know latitude and longitude to get road name. Anyone know solution how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would have to get the raw data that Nominatim is using and get the data you need out of that.  There are various tools available to parse the data or you could implement something yourself.

This question on the openstreetmap help site sounds pretty similar to what you are asking, perhaps it helps - the answers talk about some tools available to extract information out of the raw data:

[How do I list all the streets in a city with nominatim?](http://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/2980/how-do-i-list-all-the-streets-in-a-city-with-nominatim)